# Check if a file exist on a directory having only a partial name

Tags: c, linux

I need to check if a file in the format `*recipient` exists in a directory and if it does get its name. I tried with using `opendir()` and `readdir()` to list each and every file on a directory and compare it but in cases where there are a lot of files this is time consuming.

Is there any better way to achieve this? If yes, do you have small snippet showing how to do this?

Thank you, code is appreciated.

EDIT:

Just to be more clear, I need to check a directory for any file that ends in `recipient` or otherwise put `*recipient` if i were to use `ls`, if a file with that name exists then I need to get its name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The routine `glob` does just what you're looking for.  Usage examples are available here:

http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/glob.html

Here's a full example that should get you what you need:

```
#include <glob.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
    glob_t  globbuf;

    glob( "*recipient", 0, NULL, &globbuf);

    if ( globbuf.gl_pathc == 0 )
        printf("there were no matching files\n");
    else
        printf("the first of the matching files is: %s\n", globbuf.gl_pathv[0]);

    globfree(&globbuf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. See my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it the example.

Answer (score 2):

You want [`glob(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/glob) for this.

Comment: Thanks, it seems the to be the right direction, however how do I get the file name or even if it exists? In all the examples I find a lot of different strings are being set and ultimately `ls` is being called or some other utility.

Comment: It should be noted that `glob` does nothing to solve the inherent slowness of this approach. Internally it will just loop on `readdir`.

Comment: @Mr: `ls` is called to show each of the results in turn, but `glob()` is still doing the work.

Comment: Ignacio, thank you. But I guess I wasn't clear enough, I am sorry. What I need is to see if any a file in the format *reciepent exists, if it does I need to get its name. How is Glob going to help? I am trying to read the different examples but I don't see how. If you would be so kind and to explain I'd appreciate it

Comment: Call `glob()`. Check for a 0 return value. Check the `gl_pathv` member of the structure.

Comment: Maybe I am stupid but this doesn't seem to help. This is the code I am testing, could you please be more specific and post a little snippet? I'd appreciated:  glob_t globbuf;
 globbuf.gl_offs = 2;
  glob("/var/*reciepent", GLOB_DOOFFS, NULL, &globbuf);
  
  printf("%s\n", globbuf.gl_pathv);

Comment: Why are you reserving slots when you're not using them? Why are you putting a `char**` through `printf()`?